# Excel 2013 crashes when invoking function via button that closes a spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, crash

**Info**

I have a button that opens/close a spreadsheet. The button simply checks if a sheet is visible (after another spreadsheet opened) and then calls the specific function. I have two functions that either open a workbook, or close the workbook. Excel only crashes when setting the visibility or closing the workbook. If I run the code in the editor without clicking the button, everything works fine.

**Code**

```
Private Sub Main()

If Sheets("XYZ").Visible = True Then
Application.Run ("OFF")
Else
Application.Run ("ON")
End If

End Sub

Private Sub ON()

Dim Pfd As String
Pfd = ThisWorkbook.Path

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("XYZ").Visible = True
Sheets("XYZ").Select

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 SendKeys ("mso2013")
 SendKeys "~"
 SendKeys ("mso2013")
 SendKeys "~"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Workbooks.Open Filename:=Pfd & "\UserID\second.xlsx"

Workbooks("second.xlsx").Protect Structure:=False, Windows:=False, Password:="mso2013"
Workbooks("second.xlsx").Sheets("XYZ").Unprotect Password:="mso2013"
Windows("second.xlsx").Visible = True
Windows("second.xlsx").WindowState = xlMaximized

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub OFF()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Windows("second.xlsx").WindowState = xlNormal
Windows("second.xlsx").Visible = False
Workbooks("second.xlsx").Sheets("Stamm").Protect Password:="mso2013"
Workbooks("second.xlsx").Protect Structure:=True, Windows:=True, Password:="mso2013"
Workbooks("second.xlsx").Close savechanges:=True

Sheets("XYZ").Visible = xlVeryHidden
Sheets("ADMIN").Select     ' Admin is the sheet where the button is located
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I've tried timers, a button that just calls the OFF method, close without save, etc...

The problem is that it needs to be `.visible = false` and therefore I can't remove this line (without the line it would work like it should..).

---

**Solved:**

The problem was that I used a (ActiveX) Command Button instead of a normal button. No problems occurred with Excel 2010.

Comment: Why don't place `.visible = false` just before turning the screen updating back on?

Comment: thanks for your reply @R3uK but that didn't worked